# Print preview is different than what I see in browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, print-preview

**Update:** `<canvas>` rendering added to demo.
 This introduced another problem: print preview visual is **blurry**.

[image: blurry visual]

---

I have a simple page for printing EAN-13 type barcode visual. See demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/hLEIRNjq3ujoK1oIMt9Y?p=preview).

All black & white bars are nothing but `<span>` elements with some styling applied.

### Seen in browser window:

[image: Clear visual in html]

### Seen in print preview:

[image: Corrupted visual in print-preview]

As you can see;

- Second black bar has a distortion
- The last two bars supposed to be identical but they have different width.

---

What do I need to do in order to see the exact visual i have in browser window?

(Note: I'm using Chrome 48.0.2564.97 m)

Comment: There is CSS also for the print view, maybe the error is related to this.

Comment: The print preview has to round the result to screen pixels when showing on the screen, so you may have some anomalies like the last two lines not being the same width. This doesn't explain the second line though. Hm. Stupid question, but is the problem still there when you actually print to paper?

Comment: @MrLister: Well this is very funny. If I print to PDF, the problem is still there. If I print to paper, the problem seems to disappear. Bonus: If I zoom in to printed PDF, problem disappears too!